# Using mentions to add/remove roles from users

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to find a way to use the `!timeout` command with a tagged user to add the `timeout` role to them and vice versa with the `!timeoutcomplete` command.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = '<token id>';
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', message => {
    var role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('699778380937166878');
    const taggedUser = message.mentions.members.first();


    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        return message.channel.send('i dont know who you want me to put in timeout');
    }

    if (command === 'timeout') {
        message.channel.send(`${taggedUser} has been put in timeout`);

    }

    if (command === 'timeoutcomplete') {
        message.channel.send(`${taggedUser} has completed their timeout`);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For `timeout` you can do this by using `roles.add()`, like so:

```js
if (!taggedUser) return message.reply('you need to mention a user');
taggedUser.roles.add(role);
```

For `timeoutcomplete` you can do this by using `roles.remove()`, like so:

```js
if (!taggedUser) return message.reply('you need to mention a user');
taggedUser.roles.remove(role);
```